# The Bernoulli Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials, bernoulli-polynomials

We know that
[image]
where $B_n(t)$ is [Bernoulli polynomials.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials)

**My question:** Can Bernoulli polynomials be orthogonalized with respect to a [weight function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_function) $\omega$? or I mean what is a weight function under which the Bernoulli polynomials themselves are orthogonal?

If it is so, what is the weight function $\omega$, how can derive it?

Comment: Any set of linearly independent functions can orthogonalized with respect to any inner product. That means not "a" weight function, but all weight functions. Of course the orthogonalized versions are not the Bernoulli polynomials.any longer. But perhaps what you intended to ask for was a weight function under which the Bernoulli polynomials themselves are orthogonal?

Comment: Yes, I mean what is a weight function under which the Bernoulli polynomials themselves are orthogonal.

Comment: Let $w(t)=B_0(t)w(t)$, that $\int_0^1 B_n(t)w(t)dt$ is non-zero iff $n=0$ defines $w$ uniquely up to a constant. There is very little chance that it satisfies $\int_0^1 B_n(t)B_1(t)w(t)dt$ is non-zero iff $n=1$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

We [notice](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve%5B%20BernoulliB%5B6%2Cx%5D%3D%3D0%2Cx%5D) that $B_6(t)$ has $2$ real roots and $4$ complex ones. We know that polynomials orthogonal w.r. to some weight concentrated on the real axis have all the roots [real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials#Zeros).